# How to fetch words which aren't in the dictionary?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a problem with fetching single words which aren't in my dictionary (I use FULL TEXT SEARCH, exactly ispell dictionary) but the words will find in article table for title column.

Article table:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | title       |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Lorem ipsum |
| 2  | Text example|
+----+-------------+
```

For example in the following code I get words for sentence which aren't in the dictionary.

```
SELECT token
FROM ts_debug('polish', 'Text lorem ipsum lala')
WHERE lexemes is null and alias != 'blank'
```

Database returns:

```
+-----------+
| token     |
+-----------+
| lorem     |
| ipsum     |
+-----------+
```

**How to write sql code which show in table all words for article table that aren't in the dictionary? I have to use for loop and something else?**

pseudo code:

```
for i = 0; i < count(*) from article; i++
    SELECT token
    FROM ts_debug('polish', article[i].title)
    WHERE lexemes is null and alias != 'blank'
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just select all token from your article table where they are not in your current select query? That is, use the `NOT IN` keyword.

Comment: Yes, but note that checking must be in the function ts_debug.
Example: (pseudocode)
    `for count(*) from article
       SELECT token
       FROM ts_debug('polish', article.title)
       WHERE lexemes is null and alias != 'blank'
     end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the unmatched words for each article and use `DISTINCT` to filter duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT token
FROM article,
LATERAL ts_debug('polish', article.title)
WHERE lexemes is null and alias != 'blank'
```

However, with the English dictionary on PostgreSQL 9.3 your query doesn't appear to work anyway:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english', 'sdfsASDADSsfdsfsdf fred to alan word another word') where alias != 'blank' ;
   alias   |   description   |       token        |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  |       lexemes        
-----------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | sdfsASDADSsfdsfsdf | {english_stem} | english_stem | {sdfsasdadssfdsfsdf}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | fred               | {english_stem} | english_stem | {fred}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | to                 | {english_stem} | english_stem | {}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | alan               | {english_stem} | english_stem | {alan}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | word               | {english_stem} | english_stem | {word}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | another            | {english_stem} | english_stem | {anoth}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | word               | {english_stem} | english_stem | {word}
(7 rows)
```

Also, `LATERAL` is only supported in PostgreSQL 9.3. If you're on an older version you need to use a more complicated construct with `ts_debug` in the `SELECT`-list and a subquery, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (x.ld).token
FROM (
   SELECT ts_debug('polish', article.title)
   FROM article
) x(ld)
WHERE (x.ld).lexemes is null and (x.ld).alias != 'blank';
```

Comment: @Piotr PostgreSQL version? And what is the data-type `samar.i18n_localizedtext` ?

Comment: My fault. I have 8.3 PostgreSQL version. I forgot completely about localizestext. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Piotr Argh. If you're running an ancient PostgreSQL version, you need to say so in your question.